# how to schedule push notifications sent between users for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

so far I was able to send notifications from userA to UserB using url and json but I couldn't figure a way to schedule a time for the notification to be sent and I would like to repeat it every week or a month according to the user's needs, this is the code I have so far :

```
func sendNotification(to token: String, title: String, body: String) {

    let urlString = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send"
    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)!
    let paramString: [String : Any] = ["to" : token,
                                       "notification" : ["title" : title, "body" : body],
                                       "data" : ["user" : "test_id"]
    ]
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url as URL)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject:paramString, options: [.prettyPrinted])
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue("key=\(legacyServerKey)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    let task =  URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest)  { (data, response, error) in
        do {
            if let jsonData = data {
                if let jsonDataDict  = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as? [String: AnyObject] {
                    NSLog("Received data:\n\(jsonDataDict))")
                }
            }
        } catch let err as NSError {
            print(err.debugDescription)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

how can I send the notification at a specific time and how can I repeat it ?

Comment: Seems like it's not possible directly with the API, so you'd have to create a dedicated server for that, which will track the time / user IDs and will send a notification on a desired time

Comment: You should use a server. Allowing your users to send notifications without a server means that you have keys embedded in your app. This is a risk as those keys can leak.

Comment: Cron is a nice and simple to use tool that may also be of use to you. https://cron-job.org/en/

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I just have no idea how to do that through a server if you can give me some guidance please That would be greate

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tried it, you can schedule LocalNotifications for a specific time and date, on receiving of localnotification you can do it by enabling background mode.